# Double mouse click to close tab

Tags: visual-studio

I search for an option to close open document to set it double mouse click on it tab to be closed. Does anyone knows whether it's possible or not? I use VS 2019.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option. There are several ways to close a document:

- Click document's X button (closest to what you ask, and has one click less)
- Press Ctrl+F4
- Right-click in document tab and select Close
- Press Alt+F, C

You could search [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vs), but I doubt that there's an extension that supports what you want. You could also make your own Visual Studio extension, but I don't know much about them and what they can do.

If you want to close fast some documents and leave some open then try menu Windows > Windows... and in new dialog select all the documents you want to close (using Ctrl+Click, Shift+Click, and even Ctrl+A) and click Close Window(s).